# User Defined Shortcut Keys Fail to Fire Event (In Some Circumstances)

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I'm working with MS Access 2007. I have an event mapped to a command button, which works as expected when it's clicked. I've also added an ampersand in the caption field for the button command, so users can use shortcut keys (in this case alt+s) to also fire the event.

[image]

Here is the command that's executed when the command button is clicked or, depending on which fields are in focus, alt+s is pressed:

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
    If cmdSearch.Caption = "&Search Mode" Then
        cmdDelete.Enabled = False
        cmdGotoNew.Enabled = False
        cmdMenu.Enabled = False
        cmdLicHistory.Enabled = False
        cmdComplaints.Enabled = False
        cmdAddPrint.Enabled = False
        cmdReceipts.Enabled = False
        cmdLicensee.Enabled = False
        cmdSearch.Caption = "Run &Search"

        Me.Filter = "1 = 0"
        Me.FilterOn = True
        DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "frmLicense", acNewRec
        Detail.BackColor = 12615808
    Else
        Dim cntrl As Control
        Dim strFilter As String
        For Each cntrl In Me.Controls
            If TypeName(cntrl) = "Textbox" Or TypeName(cntrl) = "Combobox" Then
                If Not Len(cntrl) = 0 Then
                     If Not Len(strFilter) = 0 Then strFilter = strFilter & "and "
                     strFilter = strFilter & cntrl.ControlSource & " like '*" & cntrl & "*' "
                End If
            End If
        Next
        If Not Len(strFilter) = 0 Then
            DoCmd.DoMenuItem acFormBar, acEditMenu, acUndo, , acMenuVer70
        End If
        Me.Filter = strFilter
        Me.FilterOn = True
        DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "frmLicense", acFirst

        cmdDelete.Enabled = True
        cmdGotoNew.Enabled = True
        cmdMenu.Enabled = True
        cmdLicHistory.Enabled = True
        cmdComplaints.Enabled = True
        cmdAddPrint.Enabled = True
        cmdReceipts.Enabled = True
        cmdLicensee.Enabled = True
        cmdSearch.Caption = "&Search Mode"
'        Detail.BackColor = 12632256
        Detail.BackColor = -2147483633 ' Grey
    End If
End Sub
```

However, depending on which fields are in focus, the shortcut keys will fire or not fire. Fields that nested in option groups will fire; fields nested in a tab control will not fire.

Is this behavior expected? This is a form level event, so I'm inclined to say that it's not. Any advice on debugging this would be appreciated.

Comment: Checking: it looks like this Len will always be 0: `If Not Len(strFilter) = 0`.

Comment: I also reformatted the code - added line break after `If Not Len(strFilter) = 0 Then`. Looks like there's an `End If` missing.

Comment: At first glance I suspected that too, but it's an inner condition, so the properties for the form should still be toggled like '''Detail.BackColor'''.

Comment: Duplicate shortcut keys are unpredictable. There are multiple 'L' and 'R' shortcuts ('S' too?). Not really sure what happens but I think they won't work, at least not as expected.

Comment: Man, I thought you were on to something there, but it's (`alt+s`) not listed as a shortcut according to this https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-for-Access-6f35ab3b-6272-4c75-bb4c-f74415aa4d66